# Identity Server 4 with MVC Client That Requires Social Logins Only

Tags: configuration, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

We have a quite standard IdSrv4 configuration with a client that supports HybridAndClientCredentials grant flow (MVC web site):

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services ) {
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())                         
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
        .AddTestUsers(Users.Get())                     
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle( "Google", options => {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.ClientId = "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxxxx";
        } );
        .AddFacebook(...)
}
```

Multiple questions in regard to **MVC client's configuration**:

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services ) {

    services.AddMvc();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication( options => {
        options.DefaultScheme = ??????;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ??????;
        options.???
    } )
    .AddCookie()
    .??????
    ;            
}
```

What should be the sufficient configuration to utilize social authentication only?

Comment: What do you mean social authentication? Third party identity providers like google, facebook ?

Comment: Yes, third party providers only

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you would be still pointing your client authentication with your IdentityServer as a authority and your identityServer must be registered as a client with the third party IdentityProviders ( like google).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding OpenIdConnect middleware will be sufficient for social vendor authentication scenarios.

I'm still trying to figure out what will be the best practice to manage addtitional claims given Cookie's limitations.

```
 JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

 services.AddAuthentication( options => {
     options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 } )
 .AddCookie()
 .AddOpenIdConnect( OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; //-- change it for production

      options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
      options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

      options.Authority = "http://localhost:5010";
      options.ClientId = "xxx";
      options.ClientSecret = "xxx.secret";

      options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
      options.SaveTokens = true;

      //options.Scope.Clear(); //-- requires more research
      options.Scope.Add( "xxx-api" );
      options.Scope.Add( "email" );
      options.Scope.Add( "offline_access" );

      options.TokenValidationParameters = 
          new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name", RoleClaimType = "role" };

      //options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(); //-- requires more research
 } );
```